# The parameter name [idAktora] in the query's selection criteria does not match any parameter name defined in the query

Tags: jpa, many-to-many

I created @ManyToMany realtion between Actors(Aktorzy) and Films(Filmy). In one of my function when i call findAll() from films i get this in Glassfish console:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6094] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The parameter name [idAktora] in the query's selection criteria does not match any parameter name defined in the query.
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="aktorzy" referenceClass=Aktorzy sql="SELECT t1.IDAKTORA, t1.IMIE_AKTORA, t1.NAZWISKO_AKTORA FROM aktorzy_filmy t0, AKTORZY t1 WHERE ((t0.idAktora = ?) AND ((t0.idFilmu = ?) AND (t1.IDAKTORA = t0.idAktorzyFilmy)))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:480)
```

and the second in my opinion important part of log:

```
 Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6094] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The parameter name [idAktora] in the query's selection criteria does not match any parameter name defined in the query.
```

I think that the problem is that the query try to get all actors informations from actors_films(aktorzy_filmy) table but this is only additional  table to create ManyToMany relation and it shoult take it from Actors(Aktorzy) but i dont know how to change that.

Here's my code:

ActorDTO (part):

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer idAktora;
private String imie_aktora;
private String nazwisko_aktora;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "aktorzy")
private List<Film> filmy;
```

Films (part):

```
@ManyToMany(fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name="aktorzy_filmy",
        joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="idFilmu", referencedColumnName="idFilmu"),
            @JoinColumn(name="idAktora", referencedColumnName="idAktora")
        },
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="idAktorzyFilmy")
)


    private List<Aktorzy> aktorzy;

    public List<Aktorzy> getAktorzy() {
        return aktorzy;
    }
    public void addAktor(Aktorzy aktor){
        this.aktorzy.add(aktor);
        aktor.getFilmy().add(this);
    }
```

and where the problem occures here in client app:

```
case 12: {
                System.err.println("Uzupenij obsade filmu");
                System.out.println(filmFacade.findAll());

                System.out.println("Podaj id filmu ktoremu chcesz nadac obsade");
                int idFilmu = odczyt.nextInt();
                Film film  = filmFacade. find(idFilmu); 
                System.out.println("Dodajesz obsade do filmu "+ filmFacade.find(idFilmu).toString());
                boolean czyMaDodacKolejnegoAktora = true;
                List<Integer> dostepni=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                while(czyMaDodacKolejnegoAktora){
                    dostepni.clear();
                    for(Aktorzy a: aktorzyFacade.findAll()){
                        if(!film.getAktorzy().contains(a)){
                            System.out.println(a.toString());
                            dostepni.add(a.getId());
                        }                            
                    }
                    System.out.println("Wybierz id aktora ktorego chcesz przypisac do filmu");
                    System.err.println("0 konczy akcje");
                   int wyborAktora = odczyt.nextInt();
                   if(wyborAktora == 0){
                       czyMaDodacKolejnegoAktora = false;
                   }

                   if(dostepni.contains(wyborAktora)){
                        film.addAktor(aktorzyFacade.find(wyborAktora));
                        filmFacade.edit(film);
                   }else{
                       System.err.println("Nie możesz dodać aktora");
                   }




                }

                break;
            }
```

AbstractFacede:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
private Class<T> entityClass;

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}

public void remove(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
}

public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
}

public List<T> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    return q.getResultList();
}

public int count() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
}
```

}

and AktorzyFacade

```
   @Stateless
public class AktorzyFacade extends AbstractFacade<Aktorzy> implements app.dao.AktorzyFacadeRemote {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PPProjekt-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public AktorzyFacade() {
        super(Aktorzy.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: so you have something called findAll but don't post its content/JPQL

Comment: i work on neatbeans and i choosed create seassion beans for entity classes and it generates DAO in my bean ofc i will post it in a minute.

Comment: Apparently in your query you are not respecting the camelCase... Try just rewriting the query sentence with the correct names of your fields (respects the camelCase)